# What does the "with" keyword do in D 2.0?

Tags: d

There's a `with` keyword in D 2.0, but I'm not sure what it does, or how to use it. My search of the documentation was fruitless. Does anyone know what the use of the `with` keyword is? (Is it like C#'s `using` statement? Or like Visual Basic's `With` clause?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's right here: [With Statement](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/statement.html#WithStatement)

> The with statement is a way to simplify repeated references to the same object.

It is used like this:

```
with (expression)
{
  usage();
  writef("%s, %s", access, member);
}
```

Comment: o__o it's a statement? I was looking in the Expressions section and couldn't find it... and it's obviously not easy to search for from the search box. Thanks!! :)

Comment: you're answer would be more informative it also answered the question, rather than just linking to the answer.  D's `with` statement is similar to VB's `with` clause.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the with statement to construct anonymous objects, if you ever need that:

```
class Foo { int x; }
void main()
{
    with (new Foo)
    {
        x = 5;
    }
}
```

[This link](http://pastebin.com/kiXPeQLB) has some example code of the `with` keyword used with Scintilla.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:
"The with statement is a way to simplify repeated references to the same object. "

My thoughts when I saw it mentioned in the documentation was that it would be helpful for maths where the syntax needs to look familiar, and code repeatedly accesses the same object.

```
struct Values
{
    double x,y,vx,vy,ax,ay,dt;

    int i;
    void set_i( int i )
    {
        this.i = i;
    }

    alias int NestedType;
};



void main()
{
    //Setup:
    Values vals;
    vals.i = 10;

    //Usage of with:
    with(vals)
    // with(otherVals)    // <<--  Easy to switch the 'with' scope to deal with a different instance:
    {
        // Imports all the member symbols of the struct or class into present scope
        // without needing to refer every time to vals:
        assert( i == 10 );

        // Good for "repeated references to the same object":   Helpful for maths where the syntax needs to look familiar, and repeatedly accesses the same object:
        x  += vx*dt;
        y  += vy*dt;
        vx += ax*dt;
        vy += ay*dt;

        // Call the member functions too:
        set_i(42);

        // ... and get nested types/enums etc etc
        NestedType ex;
    }
    // Results are persist (i.e.:  all above writes were by reference:
    assert( vals.i == 42 );


    //Equivalent usage without 'with':
    {
        Values* vp = &vals;      // get a reference to vals

        assert( vp.i == 42 );

        // This looks a lot Uglier than the previous one:
        vp.x  += vp.vx*vp.dt;
        vp.y  += vp.vy*vp.dt;
        vp.vx += vp.ax*vp.dt;
        vp.vy += vp.ay*vp.dt;

        vp.set_i(56);
        Values.NestedType ex;
    }

    assert( vals.i == 56 );

}
```